# regex in Notepad++: remove any number of lines between two given expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

Input file:

```
[keyword1]
text0
"text1" = "text2"

[text3 keyword1 text4]
[text5]
[keyword2 text6]
"text7" = "text8"
"text9"
"text10" = "text11"

[text12]
"text13" = "text14"
text15
```

I want to match each 'entry' in full, if it contains a keyword in its first line. What I mean by 'entry in full' is: the first line, which is always in rectangular brackets, and any number of lines below it, basically until we hit the next [ character.

I know how to do it if I knew beforehand how many lines there would be in each 'entry', e.g. for just one line below I'd do something like this:

```
^\[(.+)(keyword1|keyword2)(.+)\]\r\n(.+)\r\n
```

But I don't know how to do it with an arbitrary number of lines. I have experimented a bit with the ". matches newline" feature of NP++, but all that got me so far was that the expressions will greedily match the whole file to the end.

Help?

//edit: so, the desired output based on the above example would be (maintaining original line numbers for clarity):

```
[text5]
[text12]
"text13" = "text14"
text15
```

//edit#2: cleared up the example input / desired output so that it's clear they are not meant literally. Q has already been answered though :)

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the conditions which you're trying to match? A bit confusing on when you want to remove lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pattern (with `. matches newline` checked) and replace with nothing:

```
\[[^\]]*?(with keyword)[^\]]*?\][^\[]*
```

Replace in the parenthesis with all the keywords separated by pipes `|`.

Basically searches for the pattern with square brackets and searching until keyword is found *inside* the brackets without checking the next line.

Since the `. matches newline` option is checked, we want to be careful when to greedily match.

[Demo in action](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yjyBX_NwBx-j5zp7)

[image]

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed. The line numbers are there for our reference.

Comment: I have removed the line numbers from the examples and changed them to make it more clear they are not meant literally now.

Comment: Your link named "Demo in action" is broken (HTTP status 502). Could move to Regex101.com or RegexPlanet.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should cover all your bases: `\n^.*[^][\n]+$`

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/mjW6Zn/2)

`\n` removes any new line characters before the line

`^.*` is designed to catch the "line x:" part

`[^][\n]+$` matches one or more characters that aren't new lines, or square brackets up until the end of the line.